# How to create a custom object from a visualforce page?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I want to create a custom object from a visualforce page not from the salesforce platform itself for dynamic purposes. Is there any way to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Metadata API to create custom objects from code.

It is possible to call the Metadata API from Apex, but you need to make some adjustments to get it to work correctly.

See [Introduction to calling the Metadata API from Apex](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/)